# Inserting project head revision number into the project files

Tags: eclipse, svn, versioning

I have a project in Eclipse under SVN versioning.

Supposing the project is composed of two files A and B, I define the revision number of the project the newest revision between A and B. So if A has rev 10 and B rev 11 the revision of the project is 11.

How can I put the project revision number into the project files?

If I'm not wrong, SVN keyword expansion is not enough as it writes the revision number of the last change to each file and not to the "project"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific svn keywords or svn command to automatically add the HEAD revision in each file. But there is a svn command to retrieve this revision number. Then you have to develop additional tooling by yourself.
Here is an extract of http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html:

> **Where's $GlobalRev$?**
>
> New users are often confused by how the $Rev$ keyword works. Since the
>   repository has a single, globally increasing revision number, many
>   people assume that it is this number that is reflected by the $Rev$
>   keyword's value. But $Rev$ expands to show the last revision in which
>   the file changed, not the last revision to which it was updated.
>   Understanding this clears the confusion, but frustration often
>   remains—without the support of a Subversion keyword to do so, how can
>   you automatically get the global revision number into your files?
>
> To do this, you need external processing. Subversion ships with a tool
>   called svnversion, which was designed for just this purpose. It crawls
>   your working copy and generates as output the revision(s) it finds.
>   You can use this program, plus some additional tooling, to embed that
>   revision information into your files. For more information on
>   svnversion, see the section called “svnversion—Subversion Working Copy
>   Version Info” in Chapter 9, Subversion Complete Reference.